# PostgreSQL SELECT LIKE datetime

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime

I have an input to search for what date to show, the input can be a date format (yyyy or yyyy-mm or yyyy-mm-dd) like '2006' or '2017-01' or '2008-10-10', i use query like this

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBER WHERE UPPER(join_date) LIKE UPPER(%".$input."%);
```

but the result is empty, is there a way to correctly use like statement for datetime in postgresql

Comment: Did you run this query on the psql cli? Why is there a stray double quotation  mark at the end? Why are you using `UPPER` when there is no text in a date field? Why did you choose the tag mysqli when it is about psql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LIKE` is for strings, not for `DATE` values. That means you must first convert the date to a properly formatted string value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM member
WHERE to_char(join_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') LIKE '%.... %';
```

Using `upper(join_date)` is subject to the evil implicit data type conversion and will not work reliably.

Also: `upper()` on a string with only numbers doesn't really make sense.